# VSCode Intellisense for SQLAlchemy query result

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, sqlalchemy, intellisense

Below is a code fragment for querying a table using SQLAlchemy and reading the first record:

```
session = Session()
customer = session.query(Customer).filter(Customer.name == "John").first()
customer.age = 50
```

In the 3rd line of code `customer.age = 50`, the VSCode Intellisense does not work, perhaps because VSCode cannot infer what will be the return type of `first()` method in the previous line.

Is there a way I can use the class cast explicitly or any other workaround, so that the methods and fields of the class `Customer` become available for its object `customer` in Intellisense?

EDIT 1:

I have declared class like this:

```
class Customer(base):
    __tablename__ = "customers"
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    age= Column(Float, nullable = False)
```

In the VSCode Intellisense, it is showing only the dunder fields of `Customer`. It is not showing the `name` and `age` fields.

Below is the screenshot how it is coming for me in VSCode:

[image]

EDIT 2:

In my VSCode, the following Python related extensions are installed:

1. Pylance
2. Python
3. Python Environment Manager
4. Python Extension Pack
5. Python Indent

Comment: Can you provide a minimum case that can be replicated? If I declare a Class `Customer`, it can correctly [identify the return type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvC1S.png) and give a [type prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbWmU.png).

Comment: I have updated my question to show the code for class Customer and the screenshot of VSCode. Let me know if you want any other details @MingJie-MSFT

Comment: I have a guess, because your code works well in my VSCode, I suppose that you haven't used the correct Python interpreter. Can you import python modle correctly? You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and tyep "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the correct python interpreter which you installed the package in.

Comment: When I choose the Python Interpreter, it gives only one option: Python 3.8.10 64-bit and even after selecting it, the IntelliSense does not work. What else can I try

Comment: Which Python related or SQLAlchemy related plugins are installed in your VSCode @MingJie-MSFT

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
customer: Customer = session.query(Customer).filter(Customer.name == "John").first()
```

With this explicit type hint, the auto completion is likely to work.

Comment: Yes, this one worked. Thanks! But I will wait to see if there is a VSCode config or an environment  (plugins, etc) related solution which does not require code change.

Comment: Can you also help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76304997/build-a-dictionary-from-sqlalchemy-table-object-for-use-with-query-update-meth?