# Build a dictionary from an object's explicitly declared fields

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My table definition:

```
class AppProperties(base):
    __tablename__ = "app_properties"
    key = Column(String, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    value = Column(String)
```

Code for updating an app property:

```
session = Session()
query = session.query(AppProperties).filter(AppProperties.key == "memory")
new_setting = AppProperties(key="memory", value="1 GB")
query.update(new_setting)
```

The line `query.update(new_setting)` fails because the update method requires an iterable.
If I use `query.update(vars(new_setting))`, it includes some extra values, which are not there in the underlying table and hence fails.

How can I build this dictionary: `{"key": "memory", "value": "1 GB"}` using the object `new_setting`, so that I can call the `update` method using this dictionary?

For example:

```
query.update({"key": "memory", "value": "1 GB"})
```

Because I already have everything in `new_setting`, I just need to convert it into a dictionary with only those keys which are explicitly declared in the class definition of `AppProperties`, without inheriting the fields from the base class or any other scope.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `new_setting`? Just pass the new data directly to the `update` method.

```
session = Session()
query = session
    .query(AppProperties)
    .filter(AppProperties.key == "memory")
    .update({ 'key': 'memory', 'value': '1 GB' })

...
```